# Whats a word that means to bounce back quickly that could also be used as a nickname?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm musing over a character idea and I'm trying to think of a nickname that might be given by close friends (in this case, the character's army squad).

My character will have a healing ability that will allow her to take some pretty hard hits and come right back. Push her down, she gets right back up. Whatever someone could dish out at her, she could take it but then give it right back.

"Bounce back" is a similar meaning to what I'm wanting, but it does not have to be completely literal. I am looking for a single word.

Two ideas I have thought of were "whiplash" since the injury is caused from the rapid *back and forth* movement or "echo" (kind of a stretch) but the whole idea of sounds bouncing back.

Comment: "Rebound" would be a name that might suit some people.

Comment: [Weebles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeble). They wobble but they don't fall down.

Comment: Does he have Adamantium claws?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things isn't on topic.

Comment: [Tigger](https://www.google.it/search?q=tigger+bouncing&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt3ZPE89jLAhXjKJoKHbnWAUkQsAQIGw) :) Or you could name her *Springer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:
**Boomerang** or **Ricochet**

Answer (score 1):

You could use *alliteration* to achieve the effect you want.

**Bounce back Bill**.

**Keep on truckin' Kevin**

**Never keep me down Neville**.

**Get back up Gertrude**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a traditional (ie not coined for an occasion) word in "to resile". Some-thing or -one able to do so is, of course, "resilient".

Comment: Don, it would be best to cite a source for this answer. Other than that, the answer is fine, if spare.